# Can I learn systemd on an Upstart system?

Tags: upstart, systemd

I want to leave my current system running with Upstart (if it ain't broke...). However, I would also like to dip my toe into systemd (in anticipation of the changeover).

Is there any way to get systemd to run in some minimal fashion on an Upstart system, so that I could easily do some or all of the following:

- try manually starting and stopping *some* daemons with systemd rather than Upstart
- try setup systemd to start *some* daemons automatically (Upstart > systemd > mydaemon)
- inspect systemd configuration
- do something fancy that only systemd can do (?)
- use systemd GUI tools (if any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. Just use a virtual machine and install systemd in it.